# Should I INCLUDE the primary key in a covering index?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Is it good, bad, or does it matter at all to `INCLUDE` the primary key in a covering index?

```sql
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX index_name_here ON dbo.table_name_here
(column_to_index_here) 
INCLUDE (primary_key_column,other_column_here)
WITH( STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE=OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY=OFF, --<default junk from SSMS
ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

I'm thinking it doesn't matter, since the PK will be in the index anyways.

My `primary_key_column` happens to be clustered, but I'd appreciate info on non-clustered primary keys as well.

I will be joining to `dbo.table_name_here` on the `column_to_index_here` column and will be then joining to other tables on `primary_key_column` and `other_column_here`.

Answer (score 82, accepted):

If you are clustering on your PK, then it **doesn't matter**.  SQL Server will disregard it since all non-clustered indexes contain the clustered index key for that row as part of their definition.

It won't use any extra space in the index, but it's redundant to include it in the definition.

If your PK isn't included in your clustered index, then only include it if you will need to retrieve that field as a part of the same query that uses the index.

Also bear in mind when you `INCLUDE` a field in an index, it's NOT in the non-leaf nodes, i.e. the index is not sorted on that value.

Comment: +1 just to add. As the OP's NCI is non unique it will also be added to the key of the NCI not just treated as an `included` column. If the `NCI` was declared as unique it would just appear in the leaf pages.

Comment: @Martin - thanks, I didn't know that.  I assumed it was at the leaf-level only as a lookup value for the row.

Comment: @Pac0 - yep. SQL Blog has gone now. Still on the WBM though https://web.archive.org/web/20190308085816/http://sqlblog.com/blogs/kalen_delaney/archive/2010/03/07/more-about-nonclustered-index-keys.aspx

Answer (score 2):

> since the PK will be in the index
>   anyways.

Assuming you mean the PK is in another index with that statement, whether or not you include the primary key in the this index depends on if you are going to be selecting it in your queries.  If you are going to select it, include it in the index, if not, leave it out.  Also for table clustered on PK, see @JNK answer.