# How to reduce query running time in SQL server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have written below query to retrieve distinct RegNo from two different tables. But below query takes nearly 25 seconds to retrieve results. In Inventory table more than 1.5 million records are there.

```
Select F.PKID, F.RegNo
From
(
  Select E.PKID, E.RegNo 
  Row_Number() Over(Order By E.RegNo Asc) RowNo
  From
  (
    Select C.PKID, C.RegNo
    From
    (
      Select Pk_Id PKID, LTrim(RTrim(A.Reg_No)) RegNo, 
      Row_Number() Over(Partition By LTrim(RTrim(A.Reg_No)) 
      Order By (Select Null)) RegRowNo
      From dbo.KeyreferenceDetails A (NoLock)
      Where A.KeyreferenceStatus = 'L' 
      And A.Reg_No Like @Value And IsNull(Reg_No, '') <> '' And Not Exists
      (
        Select 1 From dbo.INVENTORY B (NoLock) 
        Where A.Reg_No = B.Inv_H_Reg_No
      ) 
    ) C
    Where C.RegRowNo = 1 And IsNull(C.RegNo, '') <> '-'
    Union
    Select D.PKID, D.RegNo
    From 
    (
      Select Pk_ID PKID, LTrim(LTrim(Txt_RegNo)) RegNo, 
      Row_Number() Over(Partition By LTrim(LTrim(A.Txt_RegNo)) 
      Order By (Select Null)) RegRowNo
      From dbo.MobileMessageDetails A (Nolock)  
      Left Join dbo.PLACE P (Nolock) On P.Place_Shrt_Code  = A.Txt_YarddCode 
      And P.[Status] = 'L'
      Left Join dbo.INVENTORY B (Nolock) On A.Txt_RegNo = B.Inv_H_Reg_No            
      Where A.Txt_INOUT In('IN', 'MOBILE') And IsNull(A.Txt_RegNo, '') <> '' And B.Inv_H_Pk_Id Is Null 
      And A.[Status] = 'L' And Txt_RegNo Like @Value 
    ) D
    Where D.RegRowNo = 1 And IsNull(D.RegNo, '') <> '-'
 ) E
) F
Where F.RowNo > 0 And F.RowNo <= 20
```

**Query Plan:**

[image]

**Available Indexes:**

**`KeyreferenceDetails table:`**

```
 Index Name ---------------+ Column Name ----------------- + Index Type
 IX_KeyreferenceDetails_I  |  Reg_No                       | NONCLUSTERED   
 IX_KeyreferenceDetails_II |  KeyreferenceStatus           | NONCLUSTERED
```

**`Inventory table:`**

```
 Index Name ---------------+ Column Name ----------------- + Index Type
 IX_Inventory_I            | Inv_H_Reg_No                  | NONCLUSTERED
```

**`MobileMessageDetails table:`**

```
 Index Name --------------- + Column Name ----------------- + Index Type
 IX_MobileMessageDetails_I  | Txt_RegNo                     | NONCLUSTERED
 IX_MobileMessageDetails_II | Txt_INOUT                     | NONCLUSTERED
```

**`Place table:`**

```
 Index Name ---------------+ Column Name ----------------- + Index Type
 IX_Place_I                | Place_Shrt_Code               | NONCLUSTERED  
 IX_Place_I                | Status                        | NONCLUSTERED
```

I have created required indexes for all the used tables in above query. But query cost is high. How to reduce query running time in SQL server?

**`Statistics Output:`**

```
SQL Server Execution Times:
CPU time = 0 ms,  elapsed time = 0 ms.
Table 'INVENTORY'. Scan count 6, logical reads 382, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'KeyreferenceDetails'. Scan count 15, logical reads 9062, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'Worktable'. Scan count 0, logical reads 0, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'Mobile_MessageDetails'. Scan count 1, logical reads 4, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table '#TempItemsCount_____________________________________________________________________________________________________0000000118A9'. Scan count 0, logical reads 1, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'Worktable'. Scan count 0, logical reads 0, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.

SQL Server Execution Times:
CPU time = 20733 ms,  elapsed time = 7844 ms.
Table 'INVENTORY'. Scan count 6, logical reads 382, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'KeyreferenceDetails'. Scan count 14, logical reads 9062, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'Worktable'. Scan count 0, logical reads 0, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'Mobile_MessageDetails'. Scan count 1, logical reads 4, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table '#VehicleRegDetails__________________________________________________________________________________________________0000000118AB'. Scan count 0, logical reads 20, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'Worktable'. Scan count 0, logical reads 0, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.

SQL Server Execution Times:
CPU time = 21139 ms,  elapsed time = 8146 ms.
Table '#TABLE_SCHEMA_______________________________________________________________________________________________________0000000118AA'. Scan count 0, logical reads 1, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
```

**`Update:`**

```
Insert Into #TempItemsCount(TotalCount)
Select Count(E.PKID)
From
 (
   Select E.PKID, E.RegNo 
      Row_Number() Over(Order By E.RegNo Asc) RowNo
      From
      (
        Select C.PKID, C.RegNo
        From
        (
          Select Pk_Id PKID, LTrim(RTrim(A.Reg_No)) RegNo, 
          Row_Number() Over(Partition By LTrim(RTrim(A.Reg_No)) 
          Order By (Select Null)) RegRowNo
          From dbo.KeyreferenceDetails A (NoLock)
          Where A.KeyreferenceStatus = 'L' 
          And A.Reg_No Like @Value And IsNull(Reg_No, '') <> '' And Not Exists
          (
            Select 1 From dbo.INVENTORY B (NoLock) 
            Where A.Reg_No = B.Inv_H_Reg_No
          ) 
        ) C
        Where C.RegRowNo = 1 And IsNull(C.RegNo, '') <> '-'
        Union
        Select D.PKID, D.RegNo
        From 
        (
          Select Pk_ID PKID, LTrim(LTrim(Txt_RegNo)) RegNo, 
          Row_Number() Over(Partition By LTrim(LTrim(A.Txt_RegNo)) 
          Order By (Select Null)) RegRowNo
          From dbo.MobileMessageDetails A (Nolock)  
          Left Join dbo.PLACE P (Nolock) On P.Place_Shrt_Code  = A.Txt_YarddCode 
          And P.[Status] = 'L'
          Left Join dbo.INVENTORY B (Nolock) On A.Txt_RegNo = B.Inv_H_Reg_No            
          Where A.Txt_INOUT In('IN', 'MOBILE') And IsNull(A.Txt_RegNo, '') <> '' And B.Inv_H_Pk_Id Is Null 
          And A.[Status] = 'L' And Txt_RegNo Like @Value 
        ) D
        Where D.RegRowNo = 1 And IsNull(D.RegNo, '') <> '-'
    ) E
 )
```

Comment: what are the results of sys.dm_db_missing_index_details ?

Comment: Change the CTEs to temporary tables. (note, not table variables)

Comment: You seem to have indexes for the fields given as search criteria like `status` and `TXT_inout` but those are not used. Are those not really limiting the amount of data? Statistics io output might be helpful too.

Comment: If you are going to use NOLOCK (which I don't recommend) you at least to use it syntactically correct. Omitting the WITH keyword is deprecated. Also you should make absolute certain you fully understand that hint. Most people think it is only dirty reads. It if far more sinister than that. http://blogs.sqlsentry.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere/

Comment: Could you post the actual table definitions and indexes? Also, posting the actual execution plan instead of a picture would be very helpful.

Comment: Actual table definitions with primary/foreign keys would definitely help.

Comment: @RGS CPU time of 20 seconds with 9k reads with all data cached sounds really big, most likely caused by the bitmap creation. Maybe trying with MAXDOP 1 would help? Statistics IO shows temp. tables not seen in your SQL, so is that not the complete query?

Comment: @JamesZ, I have updated my question. I have to get total count of records for pagination purpose.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answering without schema and with limited information, so no guarantees this will parse, but below is an attempt to optimize it so that you can at least understand the approaches.

The optimizations can be categorized into a few points:

1. Separating the complex query into separate statements that are easier to understand (both for people & the optimizer) and are known that the optimizer will do well with.  It is easy to optimize the first query, for instance, because it is clear that `Reg_No` is used in the `JOIN` as well as the `WHERE` clause.  An example index might be:

   CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX index_name ON dbo.KeyreferenceDetails (Reg_No) INCLUDE (Pk_Id, KeyreferenceStatus) WHERE KeyreferenceStatus = 'L'
2. Eliminate functions (`ISNULL`, `COALESCE`, `LTRIM`, `RTRIM`, etc) in `JOIN`, `WHERE`, `PARTITION BY`.  For instance, consider this:

   `WHERE ISNULL(A.Reg_No, '') <> ''`

   The optimizer will not be able to use an index on `Reg_No` because you are applying a function to it.  Instead, rewrite this as:

   `WHERE A.Reg_No <> '' AND A.Reg_No IS NOT NULL`
3. Consider the use of `UNION ALL` vs `UNION`.  For `UNION`, the query engine will deduplicate the two sets and return only the uniques.  It must do that before it returns any data for processing.  With `UNION ALL` you have a concatenation that simple processes the two queries independently and appends the second set to the end of the first.
4. Rather than using an `IN` in the `WHERE` clause, you can use a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` and add a check to see that the key column from the joined table is NULL to ensure no records are returned from it, or an `EXISTS`, and this will often perform more efficiently.

Below is an example of one approach to applying some of these principles to your query:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#temp') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #temp;
GO
SELECT  PKID = Pk_Id, 
        RegNo = LTrim(RTrim(A.Reg_No)), 
        RegRowNo = Row_Number() Over(Partition By LTrim(RTrim(A.Reg_No)) Order By (Select Null))
INTO    #temp
FROM    dbo.KeyreferenceDetails A WITH(NOLOCK)
        LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.INVENTORY B WITH(NOLOCK) ON A.Reg_No = B.Inv_H_Reg_No
WHERE   B.Inv_H_Reg_No IS NULL
AND     A.KeyreferenceStatus = 'L' 
And     A.Reg_No Like @Value 
And     A.Reg_No IS NOT NULL
AND     A.Reg_No <> '';

INSERT INTO #temp (PKID, RegNo, RegRowNo)
  SELECT  PKID = Pk_ID, 
          RegNo = LTrim(LTrim(A.Txt_RegNo)), 
          RegRowNo = Row_Number() Over(Partition By LTrim(LTrim(A.Txt_RegNo)) Order By (Select Null)) 
  FROM    dbo.MobileMessageDetails A WITH(NOLOCK)
          LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.PLACE P WITH(NOLOCK) ON P.Place_Shrt_Code  = A.Txt_YarddCode AND P.[Status] = 'L'
          LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.INVENTORY B WITH(NOLOCK) ON A.Txt_RegNo = B.Inv_H_Reg_No            
  WHERE   B.Inv_H_Pk_Id Is Null 
  AND     A.Status = 'L' 
  AND     A.Txt_RegNo Like @Value 
  And     A.Txt_RegNo IS NOT NULL
  AND     A.Txt_RegNo <> ''
  AND     A.Txt_INOUT In ('IN', 'MOBILE');

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#final') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #final;
GO
SELECT  t.PKID, 
        t.RegNo,
        RowNo = Row_Number() Over(Order By t.RegNo Asc)
INTO    #final
FROM    #temp t;
WHERE   t.RegNo <> '-'

SELECT  F.PKID, F.RegNo
FROM    #final F
WHERE   F.RowNo BETWEEN 1 AND 20

GO
DROP TABLE #temp, #final
```

Since there are quite possibly syntax errors in this, when you review this ,I would recommend running each section at a time and ensuring it works, rather than executing this whole script at once.  Hope this helps!

Regards,

Ross

Comment: But above query takes nearly 14 seconds to return result. The query in my question takes 16 seconds to return result after changing some conditions. How to reduce query execution time further?

Comment: How long does each of the select statements take in my example?  Trying to understand where the bottleneck is.

Comment: Is it necessary to include Pk_Id in Non Clustered Index because Pk_Id is primary key i.e., Clustered Index in my table?

Comment: Good question - I wasn't sure if Pk_Id was used in the clustered index.  If you have a clustered index on the primary key (Pk_Id) then no you don't need to include it.  

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5328179/good-doesnt-matter-bad-to-include-primary-key-in-covering-index

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15051869/relationship-of-primary-key-and-clustered-index

Comment: Whether I need to include KeyreferenceStatus in Include column or create separate non clustered index for KeyreferenceStatus? Which one is effectively chosen by the optimizer?

Comment: Check out the index example I included after point 1 above.  The index ends with KeyreferenceStatus = 'L'.  This is a filtered index and will be a more efficient index than just creating a nonclustered with all values for that column.

Comment: In your fourth point, you said that I have to remove sub query technique i.e., Exists in where clause. From my understanding, Exists will perform better than Left outer join. Please refer below link. http://sqlperformance.com/2012/12/t-sql-queries/left-anti-semi-join

Comment: Good point - I was thinking of an `IN` instead of `EXISTS`.  From what I have seen `EXISTS` and the LEFT OUTER JOIN perform very comparably and `IN` can have wildly different execution plans.