# Do we need to add primary key to multiple columns index?

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress

Do we need to add primary key to multiple columns index ? Or it will be automatically put there ?

```
ALTER TABLE `wp_posts`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
  ADD KEY `post_name` (`post_name`(191)),
  ADD KEY `type_status_date` (`post_type`,`post_status`,`post_date`,`ID`),
  ADD KEY `post_parent` (`post_parent`),
  ADD KEY `post_author` (`post_author`);
```

Comment: The index structure depends on the storage engine being used.

Comment: Can you explain it clearer ?

Comment: . . https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/storage-engines.html.

Answer (score 0):

I've come up with a conclusion that they put ID in there because it's going to be faster with "ORDER BY ID" because the engine don't need to *sort* but follow the *index*.

[good/doesn't matter/bad to include Primary Key in covering index?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5328179/good-doesnt-matter-bad-to-include-primary-key-in-covering-index)